# Free Marker Template: Issue with height of table in free marker template. Table's height not getting reflected.

Tags: freemarker

In below email template when I am changing the height of tables (i.e. id="dueAmt1" , id="dueAmt2" ,id="dueAmt3") then its not getting reflected in email template how ever I can see the chagnes reflects when opening with browser.
Please help me to understand why changes or not getting reflected in email ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" style="border-color: white;border-width: 0;border-bottom: 0px solid rgb(230,230,230);">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="color: rgb(74,74,74);text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: bold;font-size: 14pt;">This bill compared to previous months</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" style="border-color: white;border-width: 0;">
                            <#assign maxAmount = maxBill((dAmt1)!0,(dAmt2)!0,(dAmt3)!0)>
                            <#if maxAmount == 1>
                                <#assign maxBillValue = dAmt1>
                            <#elseif maxAmount == 2>
                                <#assign maxBillValue = dAmt2>
                            <#elseif maxAmount == 3>
                                <#assign maxBillValue = dAmt3>
                            </#if>
                            <#if (maxAmount > 0)>
                                <#if dAmt1??>
                                <tr cellpadding="20">
                                    <td width="100" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        <div style="color: rgb(51,51,51);font-weight: bold;font-size: 14pt;text-align: left;">$${dAmt1}</div>
                                        <div style="color: rgb(51,51,51);font-size: 14pt;text-align: left;">${DueDate1}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <#if (dAmt1 > 0)>
                                    <td>
                                        <table id="dueAmt1" width="100%" height="50" style="border-color: white;border-width: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
                                            <tr style="background-color: rgb(230,230,230);">
                                                <#if maxAmount == 1>
                                                    <td style="background-color: rgb(255,210,0);"></td>
                                                <#else>
                                                    <td width="${dAmt1/maxBillValue*100}%" style="background-color: rgb(191,191,191);"></td>
                                                    <td class=""></td>
                                                </#if>                                  
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    </#if>
                                </tr>
                                </#if>
                                <#if dAmt2??>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;" width="100">
                                        <div style="color: rgb(51,51,51);font-weight: bold;font-size: 14pt;text-align: left;">$${dAmt2}</div>
                                        <div style="color: rgb(51,51,51);font-size: 14pt;text-align: left;">${DueDate2}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <#if (dAmt2 > 0)>
                                    <td>
                                        <table id="dueAmt2" width="100%" height="50" style="border-color: white;border-width: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
                                            <tr style="background-color: rgb(230,230,230);">
                                                <#if maxAmount == 2>
                                                    <td style="background-color: rgb(255,210,0);"></td>
                                                <#else>
                                                    <td width="${dAmt2/maxBillValue*100}%" style="background-color: rgb(191,191,191);"></td>
                                                    <td class=""></td>
                                                </#if>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    </#if>
                                </tr>
                                </#if>
                                <#if dAmt3??>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100px" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        <div style="color: rgb(51,51,51);font-weight: bold;font-size: 14pt;text-align: left;">$${dAmt3}</div>  
                                        <div style="color: rgb(51,51,51);font-size: 14pt;text-align: left;">${DueDate3}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <#if (dAmt3 > 0)>
                                    <td>
                                        <table id="dueAmt3" width="100%" height="50" style="border-color: white;border-width: 0;border-collapse: collapse;">
                                            <tr style="background-color: rgb(230,230,230);">
                                                <#if maxAmount == 3>
                                                    <td style="background-color: rgb(255,210,0);"></td>
                                                <#else>
                                                    <td width="${dAmt3/maxBillValue*100}%" style="background-color: rgb(191,191,191);"></td>
                                                    <td class=""></td>
                                                </#if>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    </#if>
                                </tr>
                                </#if>
                            </#if>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suppose it's a HTML + CSS question, not a FreeMarker question. Also, you haven't mentation if what you are reading the e-mail with. The HTML+CSS capabilities and restrictions of different e-mail clients can be different.

Comment: Actually its a email template and it is rendered differently on email and browser , I mean when changing table's height its not getting reflected in emails in which I am using these templates. But its get reflected on browser as its html. So I need help to understand what changes required to get the same.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about... your e-mail uses HTML, exactly the same HTML I assume, but e-mail agents can have restricted HTML+CSS rendering capabilities. You don't even mention what are you reading the e-mail with.

Comment: I am reading the email in outlook and there I can't see the changes.

Comment: So it's certainly the limitation of the HTML+CSS rendering of Outlook.